# Laravel 4.2 & AngularJS Insert data into multiple tables where PK in Table_1 is FK in Table_2 & Table_3

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I am very new to Laravel and currently trying to learn how it works. I work with a project where we use Laravel and AngularJS. I am currently trying to insert data into 3 different tables from one from in AngularJS, i can get the values just fine but I don't understand how I can insert the data to multiple tables. I also have a PK in Table_1 that is FK in Table_2 and Table_3 which I need to insert as well. I've been trying to figure this out for quiet a while and i really need some help.

If you need any additional information about structure or anything just ask and i will provide it not sure what you need to see :s

Best Regards
Kevin! :)

EDIT:

So I have a form in AngularJS looking something like this:

**form.html**

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" id="currency" ng-model="travelbill.Currency" ng-init="travelbill.Currency ='SEK'" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" id="exchange_rate" ng-model="travelbill.Exchange_rate" type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" id="description" ng-model="travelbill.Description"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" id="sekinklmoms" ng-model="travelbill.SekInklMoms" type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" id="sekmoms" ng-model="travelbill.SekMoms" type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
</tr>
```

From there i call my Laravel with a controller:

**Controller.php**

```
class TravelbillController extends \BaseController {


  public function index() {
    return Response::json(Travelbill::all());
  }


  public function store() {
      $validator = Validator::make(
        array(
          'ResourceId' => Input::get('ResourceId')
        ),
        array(
          'ResourceId' => 'required'
        )
      );

      if($validator->fails()){
        App::abort(500, 'Validation Error!');
      } else {
        $travelbill = new Travelbill;
        $travelbill->ResourceId = Input::get('ResourceId');
        $travelbill->Destination = Input::get('Destination');
        $travelbill->Customer = Input::get('Customer.Name');
        $travelbill->StartDate = Input::get('StartDate');
        $travelbill->StartTime = Input::get('StartTime');
        $travelbill->EndDate = Input::get('EndDate');
        $travelbill->EndTime = Input::get('EndTime');
        $travelbill->Invoice = Input::get('Invoice');
        $travelbill->TravelCompensation = Input::get('TravelCompensation');
        $travelbill->save();


        $response = Response::json($travelbill);
      }

      return $response;
  }
}
```

From here i also want to insert the`TravelbillId` which is an increment value in the database into a table called `Cost` and `Allowance` where the FK is `TravelbillId` the relations i want is either one to one on both or one to many on `Cost` and One to One on `Allowance`.

I have some models also but I am not sure they are written correctly.

**UserModel.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    protected $table = 'resource';
    protected $primaryKey = 'ResourceId';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function supplier(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Supplier', 'SupplierId', 'SupplierId');
    }

    public function resourceData(){
        return $this->hasMany('OrderResourceData', 'ResourceId', 'ResourceId');
    }

    public function reportedTime(){
        return $this->hasMany('ReportedTime', 'ResourceId', 'ResourceId');
    }

    public function approvements(){
        return $this->hasMany('Approvement', 'ResourceId', 'ResourceId');
    }


}
```

**TravelbillModel.php**

```
<?php

  class Travelbill extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'travelbill';
    protected $primaryKey = 'TravelbillId';
    protected $fillable = array('ResourceId', 'Destination', 'StartDay', 'StartTime', 'EndDay', 'EndTime', 'Invoice', 'TravelCompensation');
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function travelbill() {
      return $this->belongsTo('User', 'ResourceId', 'ResourceId');
    }

    public function cost() {
      return $this->hasOne('Cost', 'TravelbillId', 'TravelbillId');
    }

    public function allowance() {
      return $this->hasOne('Allowance', 'TravelbillId', 'TravelbillId');
    }
  }

 ?>
```

**CostModel.php**

```
<?php

  class Cost extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'cost';
    protected $primaryKey = 'CostId';
    protected $fillable = array('TravelbillId', 'SekInklMoms');
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function cost() {
      return $this->belongsTo('Travelbill', 'TravelbillId', 'TravelbillId');
    }
  }


 ?>
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, add some code so that we can help you a little more. Also describe the type of things you are trying to insert, it can help for us to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Jason i have added some code i think that should help clearify some things atleast! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've largely done your models correctly, although without the database schema it's hard to say 100%. Basically, what you need to do is save and associate the set of records, first with the *Travelbill*, then the associated *Cost* and *Allowance*.

```
$travelBill = new Travelbill();
$travelBill->ResourceId = Input::get('ResourceId');
...
$travelBill->save(); // This should populate the TravelbillId primary key

$cost = new Cost();
$cost->SekInklMoms = ...; // The value of SekInklMoms

// Save the cost to DB *and* associate the models
$travelBill->cost()->save($cost);

// The JSON will contain travelBill *and* cost due to the association above
return Response::json($travelbill);
```

This should get you across the saving issue. The important thing to understand here is that you have to save the primary model first in order to save anything relying on its existence (i.e. associating the foreign keys with the primary). Keep in mind that could also do:

```
$travelBill->save();
$cost = new Cost();
$cost->SekInklMoms = ...;
$cost->TravelbillId = $travellBill->TravelbillId;
$cost->save();
```

The different here is that you are associating the two in the database only, and not your models in this request. This means that your returned JSON will only have the TravelBill in it.

Get comfortable with either approach first, then you may want to look at wrapping the whole set of model saving in a database transaction.

Comment: Alright! I can supply the database structure if that were to help some more since i have a diagram already made. I was going to add it to the edit but i actually forgot! :)

Comment: So i got it to work. But how would i go about saving it with a transaction? I want to join these tables later to get the data if something needs to be edited.

Comment: The transaction and data retrieval are two separate things. The transaction just ensures that if either save fails, they are both rejected. This is so you aren't left with incomplete data if something fails. For retrieval, you would simply use your relations to pull both sets of data at once. I recommend asking separate questions for both of these.

Comment: i created a new question about retrieving the data :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52201042/angularjs-laravel-4-2-retrieving-data-from-multip-tables-and-joining-them