# AngularJS & Laravel 4.2 retrieving data from multip tables and joining them

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've recently started to work with Laravel and I just recently got help to insert the data into multiple tables from one controller. Now I'm trying to retrieve data from the database and populate the form if an edit is needed or if someone needs to look at the data to be able to confirm it is correct. I don't understand how I join the tables is this in the model in Laravel? Or do I have to create a join SQL query?

**Travelbill.php Model**

```
<?php

  class Travelbill extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'travelbill';
    protected $primaryKey = 'TravelbillId';
    protected $fillable = array('ResourceId', 'Destination', 'StartDay', 'StartTime', 'EndDay', 'EndTime', 'Invoice', 'TravelCompensation');
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function travelbill() {
      return $this->belongsTo('User', 'ResourceId', 'ResourceId');
    }

    public function cost() {
      return $this->hasOne('Cost', 'TravelbillId', 'TravelbillId');
    }

    public function allowance() {
      return $this->hasOne('Allowance', 'TravelbillId', 'TravelbillId');
    }
  }

 ?>
```

**Cost.php Model**

```
<?php

  class Cost extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'cost';
    protected $primaryKey = 'CostId';
    // protected $fillable = array('TravelbillId', 'Description', 'DescriptionByHiq', 'SekInklMoms', 'SekExklMoms', 'SekInklMomsByHiq', 'SekExklMomsByHiq', 'Currency', 'ExchangeRate');
    protected $fillable = array('TravelbillId', 'Description', 'DescriptionByHiq', 'SekInklMoms', 'SekMoms', 'SekInklMomsByHiq', 'SekMomsByHiq', 'Currency', 'ExchangeRate');
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function cost() {
      return $this->belongsTo('Travelbill', 'TravelbillId', 'TravelbillId');
    }
  }


 ?>
```

**Allowance.php Model**

```
<?php

  class Allowance extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'allowance';
    protected $primaryKey = 'AllowanceId';
    protected $fillable = array('TravelbillId', 'DayAllowance', 'Breakfast', 'Lunch', 'Dinner');
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function allowance() {
      return $this->belongsTo('Travelbill', 'TravelbillId', 'TravelbillId');
    }
  }


 ?>
```

Or where am i doing this join so if i get the travelbill it also gets the Cost and Allowance data with the request?

EDIT:
I need to get the data into my AngularJS form so if a person with id = 1 needs to edit his Travelbill he should be able to click a edit button and see the information ha has filled out.

Comment: *I've recently started to work with Laravel*, is this legacy project? If not upgrade immediately!

Comment: Any specific reason you use a 5 year old framework? Why not use 5.6/5.7?

Comment: Everything in the project is very old and if upgraded everything breaks. Yes it is very old but i can't upgrade it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest form of data retrieval you can do here is to do the following:

```
$travelBills = Travelbill::with(['code','allowance'])->get();
```

This is Eager Loading and will perform three queries:

- Load all the travel bills
- Load all codes that have foreign keys matching all the travelbill ids and assign them to each travel model
- Do the same with allowances

What you'll have in the end that every Travelbill model will already have an associated Code and Allowance model, allowing you to work like:

```
echo $travelBill->cost->SekInklMoms;
```

for one of the Travelbills you loaded. Note a couple of things in the first query:

- The travelbills are *not* filtered, we are loading them all at this point.
- We are doing it *simply*, not necessarily efficiently. I recommend first get comfortable with the relationships loading before get onto things like joins (which break the spirit of Eloquent ORM in any case)

Comment: You are a god! :D Thank you very much for the response i will look into this! :) I will try to play around with this and hope i get it to work :) I will keep you posted!

Comment: Alright I understand what you informed me about here, but now I'm curious to how it would work if i want to get the data to my AngularJS form and allow for it to be edited. Example: Person 1 posts a Travelbill, Admin 1 checks it and informs Person 1 that it is not correct. Person 1 want's to edit it. How do i get the data from Laravel to the AngularJS form? :o